# only 1 Thread at a time in JAVA program

Tags: java, multithreading

Here's my code (Class):

```
package table2thread;

import java.util.logging.Level;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Table2Thread extends Thread {

    private int j;
    private boolean flag;

    Table2Thread(int j0) {
        j = j0;
    }

    public void run() {

        if (Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("Thread1")) {
            for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
                System.out.println(j + "*" + i + "=" + j * i);
                flag = true;
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Table2Thread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        } else if (Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("Thread1") && flag == true) {
            for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
                System.out.println(j + "*" + i + "=" + j * i);
                flag = false;
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Table2Thread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my main class:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Table2Thread a1 =new Table2Thread(3);
        a1.setName("Thread1");
        a1.start();
        Table2Thread a2 =new Table2Thread(4);
        a2.setName("Thread2");
        a2.start();
    }
}
```

I need only 1 thread at a time and only unique one. First a1 then a2 then again a1 and a2, but right now when i run my code i get the duplication like first a1 starts then a2 then after 3-4 increments a1 starts and again a1 starts then a2 starts and again a2 starts. I tried many different things but as i am newbie i am unable to get it to work.

PLEASE HELP

Comment: If i use if else then thread2 doesn't even start.

Comment: Have you tried using a monitor lock?

Comment: No i haven't. I don't know about monitor lock.

Comment: both conditions check `.equals("Thread1")`, I'm assuming the else should check `Thread2`

Comment: You might consider taking a look at [Lock Objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/newlocks.html)

Comment: Yes i saw that David but sorry it was just a typing error, issue still remains.

Comment: Okay MadProgrammer i'll study about Lock Objects.

Comment: Why using 2 Threads if they shall work sequentially? Just use an ExecutorService and submit tasks "a1" and "a2".

Comment: I had to make 2 threads as this was asked.

Comment: but why does the second condition also check the 'flag' which is only set on the Thread1 instance and checked on a different (Thread2) instance? Even if the flag was declared static so it was shared, there is no guarantee both threads will see it in a consistent state if they run on different processors. Making the flag a `private volatile static boolean` could be the short term solution, but as some comments above I question the purpose of this. If it is a learning exercise then fine, but also consider other threading options.

Comment: Ok, assignment ... Then I'll second MadProgrammer's suggestion and add researching Conditions.

Comment: not a criticism though, the best way to learn coding is to write code, and success is a terrible teacher.

Comment: Thanks David i will try your soution

Comment: Its a learning exercise.

Comment: even with "private volatile static boolean" there are sometimes 2 occurrences of a1 or a2.

Comment: @Mansoor Akram: Of course, there are. If you create two threads, there will be two threads. The computer does what you tell it to do. If you don’t want two threads don’t create two threads.

Comment: Holger, of course i want 2 threads but i want them to work 1 by 1. not the way threads are working right now.

Comment: @Holger This is an assignment on Threading. Not the best I've seen so far, though. He's obliged to use two threads.

Comment: @Fildor: I understood that. However, there are answers telling how to prevent these threads from running concurrently. If these answers are not enough as the questioner objects the pure existence of both threads then the only answer can be, “if you create them, they will exist”.

Comment: @MansoorAkram You should accept an answer to hold up your ratio. This will help your future questions get answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a boolean toggle-flag you have to check it more than once ... like this:

(Pseudo-Code)

```
public static volatile boolean toggle = true;
```

...

```
if( isThread1 )
{
    for( ... )
    {
        while( !toggle )
        {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }
        // Do your stuff here
        toggle = false;
    }
}
else
{
    for( ... )
    {
        while( toggle )
        {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }
        // Do you stuff here
        toggle = true;
    }
}
```

You may have to check for additional conditions. For example if a1 has a different number of iterations than a2.

I know this not complete working code. But since this is an assignment, I just wanted to give you a hint to work it out yourself.

Good luck!

Edit: I do not claim that this is the best solution and it sure isn't the only one.

Comment: thanks sir, i guess i'll have to wait until my professor gives me the solution then. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to use threading in such case then?

Simply put the logic of your thread in a method (or a plain class), and in your main, just loop to invoke that method.

If you really want to use thread like what you do here, there are lots of thing you can do:

Method 1: First if you want a1 and a2 to keep running, you should have some kind of loop to keep them running again and again.  First way is have a loop in your main, and after starting a1 or a2, add a a1.join()/a2.join(), so that it will start a thread, wait until it finish, and then start the next one.

Method 2: You may have the loop in the thread instead, and both thread share a monitor/semaphore.  Before running the logic in the loop, acquire the monitor, like this:

```
public void run() {
   while (running) {
      synchronized(sharedMonitor) {
          while (flag != thisThread) {
              sharedMonitor.wait();
          }
          //your actual logic here
          flag = nextThread;
          sharedMonitor.notifyAll();
      }
   }
}
```

Method 3:
Instead of managing the thread yourselves, create a Executor.  Consider using a 2 element block queue for the executor, and you may use a 1-thread Thread Pool Executor.  So your main loop will keep creating Runnable which represent the logic of your a1/a2, and submit to the executor to `execute` the Runnable.

Comment: Method 2 does not ensure the threads execute in a toggling manner (a1,a2,a1,a2, ...). He would have to add logic for that.

Comment: @Fildor You are right.  It can be a little twist in my code, so that we add a flag with combination of wait & notify, it will serve the purpose.

Comment: Added the little piece of code demonstrating use of wait/notify in method 2

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use Thread::Join method.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Table2Thread a1 =new Table2Thread(3);
        a1.setName("Thread1");
        a1.start();
        a1.join();
        Table2Thread a2 =new Table2Thread(4);
        a2.setName("Thread2");
        a2.start();
    }
}
```

Thanks
Niraj Rathi

Comment: With a1.join it works but first a1 starts and stops after 3*10=30 and then a2 starts, i want them to work 1 by 1 till program stops.

Comment: You should get rid of those `Thread.sleep()`. They do not help. Toggling a flag was quite ok, but you are checking it only once, before entering the loop(s). What you want is to toggle it on every execution of the logoutput and then wait for it to be toggled by the other thread. A Lock object and Conditions can help you doing that.

Comment: can you show me with modified code, it was my first lecture and i don't understand anything.